# How to encrypt a PKCS#1 RSA private key with a passphrase?

Tags: openssl

I have been provided with an X509 certificate and it's RSA private key following the format below :

```
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
QrdY0v8YD4vu03G50VR14PkQHnYTrFVBIuT
.........
aB0XD0TPqROzZk2bqoRLxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxK
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
```

For my purpose i need to specify a passphrase when importing the key in order to upload it to a particular device.

If i can access the base64 content of both certificate and private key in clear, doesn't that mean that there is no passphrase or am i completely wrong ?

So I've tried encrypting this private key with a passphrase using openssl (this might be stupid) :

```
openssl rsa -in input_key.pem -passout "pass:secret" -out output_key.pem
```

However the content of output_key.pem remains unprotected.

Is there a way to reencrypt both the cert and the key with a new passphrase if it hasn't been set initially ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to:

- pick a format (PKCS#1 vs PKCS#8)
- pick an algorithm

Older  PKCS#1 format provides wider compatibility but is not FIPS-compliant due to the hardcoded use of the MD5 to derive an encryption key from the passphrase.

Here's how to get your private key encrypted using PKCS#1:

```
$ export PASS='Pa$$w0rd'

$ openssl rsa -passout 'env:PASS' -in decrypted.key.pem -out encrypted.pem -aes256
writing RSA key

$ head -n1 decrypted.key.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

$ head -n4 encrypted.pem
-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
Proc-Type: 4,ENCRYPTED
DEK-Info: AES-256-CBC,11DCCDA8D0153D4B9249F07BF2F61D88
```

Here's how to encrypt using the modern PKCS#8 format:

```
$ export PASS='Pa$$w0rd'

$ openssl pkcs8 -in decrypted.key.pem -topk8 -out pkcs8-encrypted.pem -passout 'env:PASS' -v2 aes-256-cbc

$ head -n1 pkcs8-encrypted.pem
-----BEGIN ENCRYPTED PRIVATE KEY-----

$ openssl asn1parse -i -in pkcs8-encrypted.pem
    0:d=0  hl=4 l=1311 cons: SEQUENCE
    4:d=1  hl=2 l=  73 cons:  SEQUENCE
    6:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim:   OBJECT            :PBES2
   17:d=2  hl=2 l=  60 cons:   SEQUENCE
   19:d=3  hl=2 l=  27 cons:    SEQUENCE
   21:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :PBKDF2
   32:d=4  hl=2 l=  14 cons:     SEQUENCE
   34:d=5  hl=2 l=   8 prim:      OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:7EBF972AE111001E
   44:d=5  hl=2 l=   2 prim:      INTEGER           :0800
   48:d=3  hl=2 l=  29 cons:    SEQUENCE
   50:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim:     OBJECT            :aes-256-cbc
   61:d=4  hl=2 l=  16 prim:     OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:7498A6814E3031FB00E846626289F71F
   79:d=1  hl=4 l=1232 prim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
```